# How to remove all characters standing before a specific character in notepad ++

Tags: search, replace, notepad++

i have this text

```
http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?num=100&hl=en&prmdo=1&q=cache:RZTSZuXeAgIJ:https://twitter.com/okkymintaraga+site:twitter.com+emptiness&&ct=clnk
```

i want to remove all the text before `https://twitter.com`

how can i do that?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Open up Notepad++, CTRL + H, put:

http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?num=100&hl=en&prmdo=1&q=cache:RZTSZuXeAgIJ:

... in "Find what" and leave "Replace with" blank, click "replace".

Is this a trick question?

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.+(?=https://twitter\.com)`
- Replace with: `NOTHING`
- Clic on <kbd>Replace</kbd>

Make sure you've checked `Regular Expression`.

This will replace, in a line, everything that is before `https://twitter.com`.

`(?=https://twitter\.com)` is a [positive look ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).